# Insane explanation of Swift Optionals

Tags: swift, option-type

[this page](http://appventure.me/2014/06/13/swift-optionals-made-simple/) has a "simple" explanation of Swift optionals.

The guy has examples that are insane, like this:

```
if let p = partitionArray([1, 2, 3, 4] as NSArray?) {
    // this code will be called
}

if let p = partitionArray([1, 2, 3] as NSArray?) {
    // this code won't be called
}
```

U wot? These are the same code to me, except for the fact that the second array has one element less. Why the second one will not execute is black magic or the guy is smoking really bad stuff.

He gave this other example:

```
partitionArray([1, 2, 3, 4] as NSArray?)![0] // will work fine
partitionArray([1, 2, 3] as NSArray?)![0] // will crash
```

again the same thing.

If this is a simple explanation I don't get it. Can you guys explain?

Comment: He clearly states: "*... imagine we want to split an array in two **equally sized** partitions.*"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is written in a chatty style inappropriate for this venue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the partition function does

```
if (p.count % 2 != 0) return nil;
```

and nil! will crash

Comment: ah I see now. I was assuming that in the second line it would return nil and then a message to nil would occur would be fine but swift will not allow messages to nil to pass without crashing. AHHHH... thanks.